# What is the specific flow of prfm operation in ARMv8?

Tags: caching, arm, prefetch

In ARM, **prfm** supports prefetching data to cache.

If I prefetch data to L2 cache using PLDL2KEEP first, wait until the data reaches L2 cache.  Then PLDL1KEEP is used to fetch the same data, does **prfm** get data from memory or L2 cache?

That is, is data prefetch grading feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Prefetch is entirely timing dependent. You have no guaranteed way to "wait until the data reaches L2 cache". You have no guaranteed way to ensure data stays in the cache until you need it once it gets there.

So ...

> does prfm get data from memory or L2 cache?

... it depends. If it's in cache you'll get data from cache. If it's not then you'll get data from memory. Or not at all, given that prefetch is just a hint.

Comment: Recently I have been working on a processor-specific algorithm library and have been getting a good performance boost through prefetching. I'll tweak the structure of the algorithm to make sure that the data gets to L2 and doesn't get swapped out. So you think prefetch grading is possible? Thanks. I'll try to write some assembly code to verify the problem.

Comment: It's entirely going to depend on the microarchitecture of specific processor you are targeting. Benchmarking it is going to be the only way to be sure.